# Does consuming raw onion make you thirsty?

Tags: side-effects, water, vegetable

Whenever I consume onion without cooking, I feel so thirsty. So I am drinking more water than normally. I am lean and my BMI level is below 18.5 . Is this the problem of my health or is there any reason caused by consuming raw onion?

Comment: I am searching the web for the same answer. Closest thing I've found is it's a mild diuretic and some people are more sensitive to it.  Going to continue my search...